# Dynamically creating and removing components in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to dynamically create and destroy components. Let's say I have a component `A` which has a button on click of which I create a component `B` using ComponentFactoryResolver. Now I am creating multiple instance of components by clicking on the button multiple times. My component `B` has an html something as the following:

```
<div id="container-{{index}}"
    ...more content
</div>
```

In my component `B`, I want to destroy some other instance of `B` which was created earlier. How can I get the reference to some other instance of `B` inside a new instance of `B`? Is it possible to somehow use the `id` of the underlying html to get the reference to the component?

Comment: Actually you can use dependency injection to have it, you can inject your A component in your B component, this combined with a `@ViewChildren(BClassComponent) bComponentsList: BClassComponent [];` you gonna have a reference to all B Components that you have in your A template. But I'm sure that there would be another cleaner option depends on your specific needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do what the commenter Ricardo suggested and use dependency injection.

Somewhere inside component A add a method that will be called by each child component B in their ngOnInit...

```
 componentList : any[] = [];

 addChild(component: any) { 
    this.componentList.push(component)
 }
```

Then inside the child components, inject the parent into their constructor and call the add method in the ngOnInit so the parent maintains an array of every instance of component B

```
 constructor( private parent: ComponentA) {}

 ngOnInit() { this.parent.addChild(this); }
```

Now from any B component you could access the parent components public 'componentList' property to see all the created instances. Don't forget to import ComponentA inside the ComponentB files